# Change the colors of chartkick stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, charts, chartkick

I am using chartkick in my ruby on rails app and creating a stacked bar chart. I need to know how can I set my custom colors in this case. I am dividing the chart into 2 parts, male and female. I need the chart to follow a separate color for male and a separate color for female.

This is what I am doing:
`<%= column_chart @data, {thousands: ",", colors: ["#FF9800", "#E7E7E7"], stacked: true} %>`

I am not able to find much from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful, by setting **Chartkick.options** block

[https://chartkick.com/#:~:text=To%20set%20options%20for%20all%20of%20your%20charts%2C%20create%20an%20initializer%20config/initializers/chartkick.rb%20with%3A](https://chartkick.com/#:%7E:text=To%20set%20options%20for%20all%20of%20your%20charts%2C%20create%20an%20initializer%20config/initializers/chartkick.rb%20with%3A)